# Is it impossible to calculate exact worst-case scenario like wikipedia says?

Tags: algorithm, analysis, average

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case): "it is typically impossible to determine the exact worst-case scenario. Instead, a scenario is considered such that it is at least as bad as the worst case". I do not understand that part. Isn't the worst case when searching a number in a list is when it is at the last index? Isn't it the exact worst case?

Comment: Please provide the reference. If this is about asymptotic complexity, then the Wikipedia may be wrong. If it's about Pascal's wager and the afterlife, then it may indeed be hard to determine the worst-case scenario.

Comment: @larsmans I'm curious what made you think of Pascal's wager here.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I just wrote several pages full of probability equations, I guess that made me think of good old Pascal :)

Comment: it is on the page @hatchet mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

I think you misread the entry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case

They are saying that the worst case may be something you can identify, but the exact input is not. For example, if implementing a hash table / dictionary using buckets, it's easy to say that the worst case is when all 100 sample entries hash to the same bucket, but less easy to identify 100 inputs that actually hash to the same bucket. For some algorithms, it may be next to impossible to come up with the exact worst case input data.

> Worst-case analysis has similar problems: it is typically impossible
>   to determine the exact worst-case scenario. Instead, a scenario is
>   considered such that it is at least as bad as the worst case. For
>   example, when analysing an algorithm, **it may be possible to find the
>   longest possible path through the algorithm (by considering the
>   maximum number of loops, for instance) even if it is not possible to
>   determine the exact input that would generate this path** (indeed, such
>   an input may not exist). This gives a safe analysis (the worst case is
>   never underestimated), but one which is pessimistic, since there may
>   be no input that would require this path.

Comment: While relevant, I don't think the article is trying to say something about the input per se. It's trying to say something about the "longest possible path through the algorithm" (as an example) or any other type of bound, even if you don't know *how* the bound might be achieved (slightly different from input).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the exact worst case for the scenario you mention, but the scenario you mention is a simple scenario.

Imagine a complicated operation on a tree which involves rotating nodes all the way up to the root. It may be the case that the worst-case is a complicated function of the current state of the tree. But it's much easier to imagine, say, that you need to do O(log(N)) or O(N) rotations, depending on whether you can prove that either is worst than the worst case (certainly O(N) is a bound on the worst case in this more complicated scenario).

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the worst case execution time (WCET) you would consider each loop in terms of the input size and assume that it will not terminate early. If you have a somewhat complicated algorithm, however, the input that would lead to WCET may not be computed. For example, if your algorithm uses a hash-table (of names), you can assume that all keys hash to the same cell but you cannot tell what kind of input would lead to this case. Although it may even be possible to see that the input semantics would never lead to such a hash table, you would still calculate the WCET based on the assumption that all keys have the same hash.